# Using Entity Data model EF CORE 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

i'm try migrate an application from .net 4.7 to .net core 6.

i installed visual studio 2022 with  net core 6 sdk, then  create a class library and install EF Core from nugget.

Now, want to create my class model using "ADO.NET Entity Data Model " like in .net framework 4.7 for create model from existing BD.

my class library dependences:

[image]

DataModel creation:

[image]

But it throws me the following error.

[image]

[image]

I don't understand the problem since I have .NET Core 6 installed with its sdk. What other dependency would I be missing?

Comment: efcore does not support edmx

Comment: We've recently moved from EDMX and database-first to code-first. I highly recommend it. Like all change, it takes some getting used to, but I prefer it.

Comment: Try EF Core Power Tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate your model and context from the db you need to use ef core [scaffolding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding) using the tools available, [cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell) or [PMC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell)

> Reverse engineering is the process of scaffolding entity type classes and a DbContext class based on a database schema. It can be performed using the Scaffold-DbContext command of the EF Core Package Manager Console (PMC) tools or the dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold command of the .NET Command-line Interface (CLI) tools.

Answer (score -1):

It is not supported with .NET 6.0
You can change the target framework to .NET framework 4.8
Another option is to use Repository pattern and skip using EF data modal.

I hope this would help.